# How to fix Encoding Overloaded in OBS Studio?

Tags: encoding, obs

I want to record a programming tutorial with OBS Studio in 1080p 30FPS. I have never changed the encoder, the output format is MP4. Although my computer has very good hardware, I get Encoding Overloaded after some time and the video starts getting asynchronous.
I read that the Encoding gets Overloaded when your computer can't handle the game you are playing and OBS recording, but I don't play any game, the only apps I have running are Visual Studio Code, one or two tabs of Google Chrome and OBS Studio.
What can I do?

Edit:
CPU: Intel i5-6600k
OS: Windows 10 Pro
RAM: 16GB DDR4
Video Card: PowerColor Red Devil AMD Radeon RX 480 (8GB V-RAM)
As said, I don't record games, but only have VS Code and OBS Studio running so I can't imagine that my computer is too slow.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Encoding overloaded means that your computer isn't fast enough to encode with the settings as they are now.

There are two options: 1) Encode via hardware (intel quicksync, AMD VCE, Nvidia nvenc) or set the quality of the encode lower (as in a faster/fastest x264 preset).

Without more information (CPU, GPU, Ram, OS etc) it is difficult to know what is the best way forward.

Comment: I added the information you asked for.